# bootstrap video modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

trying to create a video modal where it contains 3 images placed next to each other with individual modal..on click of these images a video modal pops up.so i created 3 separate ids in the JavaScript that on clicking will open 3 different videos..but the problem is I am able to play 2 videos the first and second but the third one does not play.when the third image is clicked it plays the first video.just unable to play individual videos on clicking individual images.how do i fix it

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myBtn").click(function(){
$("#myModal").modal({backdrop: false});
});

$("#myBtn1").click(function(){
$("#myModal1").modal({backdrop: false});
});

$("#myBtn2").click(function(){
$("#myModal2").modal({backdrop: false});
});

});
</script>

<div class="container">
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal"><img id="myBtn" src="images/video1.png">
</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal"><img id="myBtn1" src="images/video1.png">
</a>
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal"><img id="myBtn2" src="images/video1.png">
</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
<iframe class="size" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/PD0Yd0l3-0I?autoplay=1";frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
<iframe class="size" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jiji_1iosv4?autoplay=1" ;frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
<iframe class="size" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/y8gvEtmay9M?autoplay=1" ;frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems to a javascript problem

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript to open the modals. You can just use the HTML tags. However, you will need to manage playback (stop on close, etc.) with JavaScript.

```
<div class="container">
<a href="#myModal" data-backdrop="static" data-toggle="modal"><img id="myBtn" src="images/video1.png">
</a>
<a href="#myModal1" data-backdrop="static"  data-toggle="modal"><img id="myBtn1" src="images/video1.png">
</a>
<a href="#myModal2" data-backdrop="static"  data-toggle="modal"><img id="myBtn2" src="images/video1.png">
</a>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
<iframe class="size" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/rFuEu3dj-nA?autoplay=1" ;frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="myModal1" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
<iframe class="size" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZHfRHKbd_fE?autoplay=1" ;frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
<iframe class="size" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JCdfecir86Y?autoplay=1" ;frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is a JavaScript Version

https://jsfiddle.net/aaronfranco/L6xvLcuL/14/

Comment: thanks a lot it worked, but if i want a javascript function will it work?

Comment: also it is not smooth as before when the modal pops up after you modified it

Comment: Added a javascript version.

Comment: there is problem even before i click on the image, all the videos start playing at the background after a few seconds, that is the audio plays until i have to close the browser..is there a workaround